# Issue with OOB Role 'Salesperson'

Tags: security, dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-365

I created a new app and set it up so that only two roles 'System Administrator' and 'System Customization' have access to it. However, I've noticed that a user with the 'Salesperson' role, but without the 'System Administrator' or 'System Customization' roles also has access to the app. When I remove the 'Salesperson' role from a user, he lose access to the app. Conversely, when I assign him the 'Salesperson' role, they gain access. Attached is a screenshot showing the permissions and the result from AppAccessChecker.
[Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t4n1x.png)
[result from AppAccessChecker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELZqm.png)

I tried republishing the app, but nothing changed.

Comment: It seems the role 'Basic user' gives access to the app as well. Does that ring a bell?

Comment: @HenkvanBoeijen No, it's just the cursor hovered over.